Application of a Template Chart Gone Wrong on SPSS
Afternoon!
Using SPSS, I made my edits in one bar chart — e.g., font type and size, hiding grid lines, and colours, namely: blue, orange, green, purple, and grey for 5 bars, respectively, etc. — and I saved the chart as a template to apply to the remaining charts in my data/item analysis.
When I analysed another item (from the same questionnaire section) and applied the saved template to it, the font features and grid lines applied successfully; however, the colours part did not take effect (and graph bars remained a default blue), although I thought I made no mistake in the template saving procedure.
Doesn't SPSS save bar colours in templates, or have I made a mistake?
